# Add cell having a table to outer table using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a cell having a table to outer table.
I'm getting following error.

> "Adding a cell at the location (6,0) with a colspan of 1 and a rowspan
>   of 1 is illegal (beyond boundaries/overlapping)"

This seems to be like a bug in itextsharp.

1. I find a each control in html table. If this control is Table i call
   it 'tblinner'.
2. I'm finding a control(in this case all controls are labels) inside
   'tblinner' and adding it to itextsharp table.
   How may i overcome this?

   ```
                           for (int i = 0; i < tblInner.Rows.Count; i++)
                       {
                           iTextSharp.text.Table tblnested = new iTextSharp.text.Table(4);
                           iTextSharp.text.Table tblnestedbig = new iTextSharp.text.Table(1);
                           iTextSharp.text.Cell pdfTCell = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                           iTextSharp.text.Cell pdfTCellbig = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                           foreach (TableCell tCellInner in tblInner.Rows[i].Cells)
                           {
                               pdfTCell = new iTextSharp.text.Cell();
                               int cc = tblInner.Rows[i].Cells.Count;
                               Control tControlInnerLabel = tCellInner.Controls[0];
                               pdfTCell = AddControlBGToPDFTable(tControlInnerLabel, tblnested);//This function adds the control such as lable or image to tblnested
                               tblnestedbig.AddCell(pdfTCell);
                           }
                           pdfTCellbig.AddElement(tblnestedbig);
                           pdfTable.AddCell(pdfTCellbig);//i get error here
                       }
   ```

Here is what 'AddControlBGToPDFTable' does.

```
private static iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell AddControlBGToPDFTable(Control tControl, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable pdfTable)
{
(tControl is Label)
{
 Label lbl = (Label)tControl.FindControl(tControl.ID);
 // add some style to control
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell pdfTable2Cell2 = null;
 pdfTable2Cell2.Colspan = 1;
 pdfTable2Cell2 = pdfOrigTCell;
 pdfTable2Cell2.AddElement(new   iTextSharp.text.Phrase(25f,lbl.Text.Replace("<br>", "\r\n").Replace("<br />", "\r\n"), new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.HELVETICA, 12, style)));
pdfTable.AddCell(pdfTable2Cell2);
return pdfTCell;
}
}
```

1. It takes a control passed to it.
2. Create a cell and put this control to cell and add the cell to table
   that is passed as param to it.

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing what `pdfTable` and `tblInner` are about. Please **do not post your complete code** (nobody will read it), but write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that allows people to reproduce the problem so that they can explain how to solve it.

Comment: It seems like a bug in itextsharp. you cannot add a cell containing table to outer table. So i changes all my tables to pdfptables.
Thanks @bruno will keep that in mind.

Comment: I do not accept bugs based on hearsay. I only file a bug report if I can reproduce a problem. Which version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: I read it on following link that this is probably a bug.
http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/Possible-bugs-in-iTextSharp-4-0-4-0-td3768.html

Comment: That's about an iTextSharp version dating from 2007. Many bugs have been fixed in the eight years since iTextSharp 4.0.4.0 has been released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should post also code for method AddControlBGToPDFTable, that we can see what properties are you setting to cell.

Instead of creating cell with label you can use `PdfPCell` and `PdfPTable`.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();
cell.Phrase = new iTextSharp.text.Phrase("some text");
```